# How should I construct my embedded software? I'm using an MBED to control multiple sensors/motors

Tags: arm, embedded, mbed

I'm trying to improve the structure of an embedded program I'm working on.

Basically I have a program on an MBED that gets data from an IMU and moves some motors (without going into too much detail of what the system does).

What I'm trying to do at this point is improve the structure of the program.

I have a main class, I setup hardware (and pins) in a separate class called "System", IMU in it's own class "IMU", motor drivers in their own class "MotorDrivers", and so on for each sensor.

I was told by another engineer/programmer that I should setup my "system" to make everything static functions, for example (under system):

```
// system.cpp

MODSERIAL & pc()
{
    static MODSERIAL pc(USBTX, USBRX);
    return pc;
}

IMU & imu()
{
    static IMU imu(p28, p27);
    return imu;   
}

//system.hpp

MODSERIAL & pc();
IMU & imu();
```

This works, but I'm wondering if I'm not being as concise or efficient or clear as I should be when, for example, I want to use the serial port in multiple classes. I was thinking that needed to be a friend class or inherited class.  The way I'm doing it now I would write "pc().printf("print something");" to make the printer work in the class and I would have to include the system header in that class.

Comment: There you have a `static` variable in a global function,not a global variable as stated in the question.  Returning a non-const reference to a static does not provide any protection over a simple global.  However it provides control over when the constructor is called.  Beyond that your question is way too broad, and largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Clifford, I'll try to restructure this and repost it.

Basically what I'm trying to get at it is if I should use static functions to access my classes or is there a better way to do that.